# How to prevent asterisk with Enter is pressed inside C# /* */ comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, comments, editor

In VS2012 C# text editor, when Enter is pressed inside `/*  */` comments, new line is added, beginning with `*`. Is it possible to disable this behaviour and get just an empty new line?

From Visual Studio About box, Installed products:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012
Microsoft Visual Basic 2012
Microsoft Visual C# 2012
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012
Microsoft Visual F# 2012
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker
NuGet Package Manager
PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer
```

Comment: Note that this is not the default behaviour (I just tested) - do you have any add-ins like Visual Assist installed?

Comment: @RogerRowland - the question is edited. Visual Assist is not installed.

Comment: Sorry, this happens in C# editor, and not in C/C++ editor. The question is edited.

Comment: You can press Ctrl+Z to get rid of it again, it gives you exactly what you ask for.  Strikes me that you now have two problems, most programmers like their comments indented with the program text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like this has [annoyed other people](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/a41e3652-efe2-4f81-ad3e-94994974fcb2) for a long time, but as you can see if you read that thread, there is a non-intuitive hack to stop it doing this. You have to set the following option to unchecked:

`Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Generate XML documentation comments for ///`

Screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

The only downside, is - as the original post says:

> Unfortunately, turning this off not only disables the leading asterisk for block comments, but of course also disables the auto-complete feature for XML documentation comments.

Comment: @AlexFarber - lol, maybe VS2525 (who remembers Zager and Evans?)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to disable in VS2015:

Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Editor Help > 'Insert * at the start of new lines when writing /**/ comments'.